# Mathematics expression evaluated by both Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

I am building a web app with Python in backend and Angular for front end. One function is to evaluate math expressions, which need to be done in both server side and UI side. In python, I evaluate the expression with `numexpr` and intend to use `mathjs` for js

However, the expression understood by python might not have the same meaning for javascript, e.g. `a^b` is XOR in python but exponential in js.

What approach should I use to work around this so that for the same expression, js will return the result that python returns.

Comment: You can create REST [end-point](https://restful.io/an-introduction-to-api-s-cee90581ca1b) on backend side and use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) on frontend side to get the result.

Comment: @SergeyN I want to calculate on the UI side on the fly provided the math formula instead of calling the rester once again. As this calculation will be done repeatedly when user changes the input before finalizing. The idea is to pass the formula around and return the result.

Comment: The most obvious solution is to do text conversions of the formula before it's pass to the Python and same thing after.